# AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'get_audio_path'

Tags: python

I am engaging a project now, and the library *utils* might be frequently used. However, I just cannot normally invoke functions from utils. See code below.

```
import IPython.display as ipd
import librosa
import librosa.display
import utils

filename = utils.get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 2)#AUDIO_DIR is an audio path
print('File: {}'.format(filename))

x, sr = librosa.load(filename, sr=None, mono=True)
print('Duration: {:.2f}s, {} samples'.format(x.shape[-1] / sr, x.size))

start, end = 7, 17
ipd.Audio(data=x[start*sr:end*sr], rate=sr)
```

Plus, I had installed library *python_utils* either, but didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `from . import utils`?

Comment: what does `dir(utils)` return?

Comment: Add some insight about this `utils` module.

Comment: from . import utils seems didn't work.
dir(utils) returns ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']